# How can I receive desktop alerts when I receive gmail from a specific sender?

Tags: gmail, notifications

I am in a volunteer fire brigade and live in fringe pager and phone range.  I have set up so that pages are now also sent to me by email - this works well.

But I don't like (or want) to check email constantly and am looking for a way to have some sort of alert when email from a specific sender arrives.

I tried GMail Notifier but that alerts for everything.

I considered filtering to another GMail account and that would work if I had Notifier on that account only, but it seems a bit clunky - this will be what I settle for unless someone has another suggestion.

Comment: Check out "if this then that", a web application that seems to fit your needs https://ifttt.com/wtf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a filter that marks all mail, except for that specific sender, as *Not important*, and set up GMail notifications for only *Important* messages.

The filter string would be something like `from:-firedepartment.gov`(notice the `-` sign), and the action *Never mark it as important*.
[image: Screenshot of the Create filter dialog, part 1]
[image: Screenshot of the Create filter dialog, part 2]

To be sure your fire alarms are marked as important, you should also create a reverse filter, so that all mail from `firedepartment.gov` is marked as important. Simply repeat the steps above, entering the email address without the `-` sign, and selecting *Always mark it as important*.

In GMail's settings, on the *General* tab, scroll down to *Desktop Notifications* and select *Important mail notifications on*:

[image: Screenshot of the Desktop Notifications setting]

This, of course, rules out the possibility of using the *Important messages* feature for anything else than your fire alarms.

Comment: Thanks, that is the most workable solution I have found.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with the help of IFTTT.

1. Activate your Gmail channel in IFTTT.
2. Next set up a trigger on "any new mail" with the FromAddress as the email address of any particular sender.
3. For the action, choose your mobile and you'll get an SMS when a new email from that sender arrives in your mailbox.

Comment: You didn't read the question "live in fringe pager and phone range".  I already get the pages by SMS...when I go out.

Comment: Where would you like to receive these alerts?

Comment: On my windows PC.  A pop up or a sound.  As I suggested, maybe having a specific account for this email only and then gmail notifier.  It is the only solution I can think of which is why I asked here.